# case statement v day-1 in join why different results?

Tags: sql, netezza

I'm joining a list of ids that come from a fixed date and want to return the data from a previous day in another table I have two methods but they return different results. The date is a fixed date of 2017-01-02

```
on a.id = b.id
and a.date = b.timestamp-1
```

I also tried a case statement

```
on a.id = b.id
and case when date = '2017-01-02' then b.timestamp = '2017-01-01' end
```

Any ideas why this produces different results?

Comment: Please provide the ddl or definition for the columns involved, and some description of the output you are getting

Answer (score 1):

Use `DATE_SUB()` to perform date arithmetic:

```
ON a.id = b.id
AND a.date = DATE_SUB(b.timestamp, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: Hi, we use Netezza and it seems like DATE_SUB is not a supported function

Comment: I don't know Netezza, my answer is for MySQL. Check the Netezza documentation, it probably has date functions that are similar.

Comment: Don't use the MySQL tag if you aren't using the MySQL database.